# how to re run script if error and automation

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am looking for a solution to automate my script to re-run in an infinite loop till the script is stopped, and also i am having difficulties to let the script continue after any error, it should just re-start the process.

At current, if all goes well it will run for some time till i get and error, then requires me to re-run the script manually evetime, here is the error i receive:

```
? new Error(`${response.errorText} at ${url}`)
                  ^
Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED at https://*********.com
at navigate (file:///C:/Users/Omega/Desktop/GOLOGIN/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Frame.js:210:23)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async Frame.goto (file:///C:/Users/Omega/Desktop/GOLOGIN/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Frame.js:180:21)
at async CDPPage.goto (file:///C:/Users/Omega/Desktop/GOLOGIN/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Page.js:436:16)
at async file:///C:/Users/Omega/Desktop/GOLOGIN/create.js:65:3
```

Here is my full code:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-core';
import GoLogin from './node_modules/gologin/src/gologin.js';

const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const { connect } = puppeteer;

function fingerprint(){

(async () => {
  const GL = new GoLogin({
    token: '********************',
  });

  // Generate Random Profile Username
  let randomProfile = Math.floor(Math.random()*89999+1000000)

  // next parameters are required for creating

  const profile_id = await GL.create({
    name: randomProfile,
    os: 'win',
    navigator: {
      language: 'enUS',
      userAgent: 'random', // get random user agent for selected os
      resolution: '1920x1080',
      platform: 'win',
    },
    proxyEnabled: true,
     proxy: {
        mode:   'http',
        host:   '********.com',
        port:   '10000',
        username:   '*******',
        password:   '*******',
        autoProxyRegion: 'us',
     },
  });

  console.log('profile id=', profile_id);

  await GL.update({
    id: profile_id,
    name: randomProfile,
  });

  const profile = await GL.getProfile(profile_id);
  console.log('new profile name=', profile.name);

  // Goto site and wait, then delete profile
  const { status, wsUrl } = await GL.start();
  const browser = await connect({
    browserWSEndpoint: wsUrl.toString(),
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://*************.com');
  await delay(5000);
  console.log(await page.content());
  await delay(15000);
  await browser.close();
  await GL.stopLocal({ posting: false });
  await GL.delete(profile_id);
  console.log('Success');

})();

};

function run() {
    setInterval(fingerprint, 25000);
  };

  run();
```

Would appreciate if someone could guide me or show me a better way to automate the loop and also if an error the system should just re-run the script.

Comment: Did you try a `try`/`catch`?

Comment: yep, i think i put the try / catch in the incorrect order to ensure it works, at current no success so will try again

Comment: `(async () => { for (;;) { try { /* all of your code */ } catch (err) {} } })()`

Comment: You can also use pm2 package, install the package and start your program using pm2 start appname, instead of node appname, you can also configure pm2 to boot up program every time your system reboots. I've found this package pretty helpful so far